# codeigniter can't load when using a different port for localhost for db

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, xampp, localhost

so i have codeigniter setup locally(localhost), and my localhost is port 8012.  When i change the `$db['default']['hostname'] = "localhost";` to `$db['default']['hostname'] = "localhost:8012";`, codeigniter gets stuck loading but never (re)loads the page.  I'm on codeigniter 1.7.2

**EDIT**

i GOT IT.  its because i changed my mysql commands to mysqli(for newest php version) and that threw off codeigniter.  And yes, $db['default']['hostname'] = "localhost" not "localhost:8012".  But it's still codeigniter's fault for not displaying the mysql configuration issue instead of just a general one.

Comment: Your apache is on port 8012, but mysql is still on default port (3306 if I remember).

Comment: correct, but $db['default']['hostname'] is referring to localhost right not the db host, right?